# inflated pricing using ec2 on aws. data transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 service in AWS, in which the only thing I do is upload a .txt file 4 times a day, which all my clients, when using my software, use the last txt I uploaded, it can be updated by all as many times as they want in the day.
Lately with the EC2 service I am being surprised by the cost of ec2 $0.090 per GB - first 10 TB / month data transfer.....
I wanted to know if there is another option to continue using an AWS service where I can host these txt, my clients can consume it and not pay as much as I am doing (more than 200 dollars per month)
DISCLAIMER I AM FROM ARGENTINA

Comment: $200 pays for 2.2TB of data transfer at 0.09/gb.  Does 2.2TB seem like the volume you'd expect?  Seems like a lot of data for a text file, but I don't know how big your text file is.  Is the client software smart enough to not download the same copy over and over again?   How big is the txt file?

Comment: With just the information you've already provided, sounds like avery good fit for S3 and CloudFront.  Cloudfront data transfer is a little cheaper, but more importantly you get 1TB transfer free each month, so that should save you some money right there.  Cloudfront is HTTP/HTTPS though so if you're not using HTTP it won't help

Answer (score 0):

ok the first thing that you have to know is that all the data uploaded is free, BUT if you expose your instance through AWS Load Balancer you will be charged for connections and data processing, the data transfer fees in AWS is basically a head ache IMO.

My suggestion -> AWS S3
If your txt files can be publicly accessible or you can modify your app to create S3 pre-signed URLs to make the files privates but accessible from your customer side, put those files in AWS S3, basically you will pay exactly the same data transfer fee but you will save on Ec2 instance capacity and EBS is a little bit more expensive than S3, additionally you don't need to care about HA or backups.
I think you don't need Cloudfront at the very beginning

Comment: this answer raises the question, Have you used Cost Analyzer to verify that it's data transfer causing your $200/mo charge, @RuralSantaFe?